# Error in SQL 2018 Custom Map

Tags: sql-server

Good day.
I am trying to create a stored procedure where the MEMBER ID is custom auto-incremented as follows

"AP202170001"
"AP202170002"
"AP202170003"

and so on as it goes by registering data in the affiliate table.

**I have the following query that shows me what I want**

```
SELECT 'AP' + DATENAME(YEAR,GETDATE())+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),MONTH(GETDATE()))+ RIGHT(CAST((POWER(10, 6) +
 CAST(ISNULL(MAX(IDAFILIADO), 0) + 1 AS VARCHAR(5))) AS VARCHAR(7)), 6)
AS IDAFILIADO
from AUT_AFILIADO_PUNTOS
```

[image]

**But when I run the query again, it throws me the following error message**

[image]

It is not adding the correlative or in which part I am making a mistake, the data type of the IDAFILIADO field is char (13)

Comment: `ISNULL(MAX(IDAFILIADO), 0) + 1` Look closer! Your column is varchar, correct? It contains values like "AP202170001". You attempt to **add** 1 (as in math) to that value. At least that's my guess - posting a script that demonstrates your issue is far preferable to describing in words and pictures.

Comment: And you will likely regret not using 2 digits for the month number - something you will not realize until October. Your explanation and your code and your images don't quite match either. Do you want a sequence number of 4 digits or 5 digits? Casting a number to varchar does not magically add leading zeros. There is more work needed for this logic.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

On heavy duty server this could cause trouble if you define `IDAFILIADO` as unique or primary key

This will also work with two digits month numbers

> ```
> CREATE TABLE AUT_AFILIADO_PUNTOS (IDAFILIADO VARCHAR(20))
> GO
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO AUT_AFILIADO_PUNTOS VALUES('AP202170001'),( 'AP202170002'),( 'AP202170003')
> GO
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 'AP' + DATENAME(YEAR,GETDATE())+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),MONTH(GETDATE()))+ RIGHT(CAST((POWER(10, 6) +
>   CAST((ISNULL(MAX(SUBSTRING(IDAFILIADO, 3,  LEN(IDAFILIADO))), 0) + 1) % (POWER(10, 4)) AS VARCHAR(5))) AS VARCHAR(7)), 6)
> AS IDAFILIADO
> from AUT_AFILIADO_PUNTOS
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> | IDAFILIADO    |
> | :------------ |
> | AP20217000004 |
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 'AP' + DATENAME(YEAR,GETDATE())+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),MONTH('2020-11-01'))+ RIGHT(CAST((POWER(10, 6) +
>   CAST((ISNULL(MAX(SUBSTRING(IDAFILIADO, 3,  LEN(IDAFILIADO))), 0) + 1) % (POWER(10, 4)) AS VARCHAR(5))) AS VARCHAR(7)), 6)
> AS IDAFILIADO
> from AUT_AFILIADO_PUNTOS
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> | IDAFILIADO     |
> | :------------- |
> | AP202111000004 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=19544dc13f46dda9f548e03ce6b4ce51)*